# What is meant by Hinton when he refers to "Part-Whole Hierarchies" in his GLOM framework

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, papers, semantic-segmentation

I was recently reading Hinton's GLOM idea [How to represent part-whole hierarchies in a neural network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.12627.pdf), and I am simply unsure about what exactly he means when he says parsing images into "part-whole hierarchies".

Moreover, wouldn't semantic segmentation "parse" the parts from the whole image? So what is different here?